Help for Proof of the hausdorff recursion formula
For all infinite cardinals κ and λ, ${(κ^+)^λ}$ = $κ^λ$•$κ^+$
And the Proof goes as follows.
Proof:
First assume that κ<$2^λ$. Then ${(κ^+)^λ}$ = $2^λ$ = $κ^λ$ = $κ^λ$•$κ^+$
Νow assume $2^λ$≤κ. Then λ<$κ^+$ and the regularity of $κ^+$ allows us to conclude that $κ^+$ ≤ ${(κ^+)^λ}$ = |$^λ$($κ^+$)| = |$\bigcup_{γ<κ^+}^{} {^λγ}$|≤$\sum_{γ<κ^+}^{} |^λγ|$ = $\sum_{γ<κ^+}^{} |γ|^λ$ ≤ $κ^λ$•$κ^+$
Well i feel Like some of These equalitys Arent really trivial and i dont really get how they are deducing that. Especially the whole First Line of equalitys i dont really get.
And the second one is also kinda hard
Hope you Guys could Help me with that.
